# PHPExcel-1.8 Message: Cell coordinate can not be a range of cells

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have a problem with PHPExcel2018 downloaded on github

myphp page:

```
require(APPPATH.'/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
            require(APPPATH.'/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');
            $id_fondimpresa=$this->input->post('id_fondimpresa');
            $this->load->library('excel');
            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
            $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("");
            $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("");
            $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("");
            $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("");
            $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("");
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            // set Header
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1:A4', 'Calendario Attività');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A6:B6', 'ID Azione Formativa:');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D6:F6', 'Titolo Azione Formativa:');

    $filename = "tutsmake". date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").".xlsx";
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');  
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
            exit;
```

its a simple and basicaly configuration that i copy on tutorial

but I get this error message:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: PHPExcel_Exception
>
> Message: Cell coordinate can not be a range of cells.
>
> Filename:
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cubo/application/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php
>
> Line Number: 1172

like photo attached [image]

can you help me ? thanks

Comment: Just based on the message your use of `SetCellValue` appears to be specifying a range of cells but should be specifying a single cell.

Comment: @Dave Genius !!!